Creating an infinity tunnel in Illustrator
I am trying to create an infinity tunnel in Illustrator that must look like this (I don't need the rainbow parts, these can just be white):

I am running into several challenges: the thickness of the black circles is not consistent (thinner on one side), the circles do not follow regular increments in size a we move towards the center (meaning the left/right thickness of the circles doesn't change at the same percentage as the diameter of the circle), parts of the inside circles are hidden (the white/blue spaces on the left), etc.
I have tried duplicating a circle object with uneven stroke width and scaling it, and moving it to the center, but scaling down made the thickness too thin. I have tried using a white or black center-aligned stroke on the edge of each circle to adjust the thickness (but the adverse effect was that the thinner side of the circle would disappear), I have tried using Blend between the outside and inside circles, but that created compound paths that were difficult to work with.
I am running out of ideas and think I may just need to trace over the reference image and draw each circle by hand, and hope the result will look as regular.
Are there other ideas I have not tried that could make the precise recreation of this image possible?

Try 3D effect. It's like an interior view of a torus. The next screenshot shows my test. https://i.sstatic.net/3k3oQxlD.jpg  It's only a 60 degrees section of a full torus. The bar pattern is used as mapped art and there's a heavy perspective. Legacy 3D revolve is too unreliable and difficult to control  for perfect answer. But you may have more luck with the dimensions and, perspective. No shading for the mapped art!

It's clearly a 3D effect. However, it's probably just a bit beyond the limits of Illustrator's basic 3D capabilities. Better to use an actual 3D modelling application such as Blender.  My guess would be that it was probably created with 3D software anyway.  There's even a Blender Stack Exchange if you get stuck.

I suspected in a comment it might be an interior view of a piece of torus which has a stripe pattern as mapped art. But making it look right with Illustrator's 3D legacy revolve was too difficult due poor available controls, so it remained a suggestion.
Another possibility which offers a little more control is to utilize the common 3D ambiquity concave versus convex which is used in many optical illusions. In this case your tunnel could also be a circular mountain top if the mapped art is well selected. An example

The shape to be revolved with legacy 3D  effect is ABC. There's 3 nodes. A and B have horizontal handles. C is a 90 degrees corner of a rectangle. The grey fill can actually be anything, but there's no stroke!
The mapped art symbol contains blue and white (no-stroke) rectangles. It must be dragged to the symbols panel.
Applying legacy 3D revolve to the grey shape gives at first this:

The shading is not needed in this case, but it helps to see the divergence of the calculations which happens often with legacy 3D effects. Adobe has not bothered to make it perfect during the last 20 years. If the shape disintegrates it's often useful to turn the view a little.
Placing the stripes as mapped art gives this:

Rotating the view and adjusting the perspective gives finally this:

As said above, Illustrator miscalculates it easily due its buggy math. You can get also this:

You must adjust the viewing angles and the perspective to find a successful rendering.
If you expand the appearance to make the parts free for coloring or other edits you must release numerous groups and clipping masks before the parts are really separated.
BTW. Expanding the appearance of the last (miscalculated) version and releasing the clipping masks and groups changed the result to this:

It resembles the wanted result and maybe could be used if the perspective was at first adjusted a little less steep.

Thanks for this amazing answer! I followed another commenter's idea and got pretty good results in Blender - with a higher level of accuracy and almost instant calculations allowing for unlimited variations. Did you mean to add something at the very end of your answer? It ends with a colon.

There's nothing to add. It's fixed.
